# MongoDB - how to aggregate based on duration between documents?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to aggregate event documents into session documents based on the time difference between them:

- if (time difference > 20min) -> create separate sessions
- else -> merge into same session

I am looking at map-reduce and the group&aggregate commands, but haven't come up with a solution that lets me do this.

**Conditions**:

- should be race condition proof
- will need to handle data as it becomes available (not necessary chronological)
- max time difference between events = 20min

**document structure**:

```
    Event = Schema({
      start: Date,
      end: Date,
    })

    Session = Schema({
      start: Date,
      end: Date,
      duration: Number //will be an aggregate for the time of the events, ignoring the time in between
    })
```

**best solution so far (NOT efficient & NOT race condition proof)**:

for every `new_event = {start, finish}`:

```
    1. matched_events = Sessions.find{ start:{$lt:new_event.finish+20*60*1000},finish:{$gt:new_event.start-20*60*1000}, 
    2. new_session = {start: $min:{matched_events.start}, finish: $max:{matched_events.finish}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried to do? Show us some code on where you are stuck, it will help us figure out the problem.

Comment: I am looking at different commands available in mongodb and can't find a way to dynamically use the duration between events to aggregate. 

Currently my best idea is to aggregate outside of mongodb by using queries ($gt, $lt operators) and write back to mongo, but then I can run into race conditions, which would create multiple sessions.

Comment: I see, would you post an example of your documents? I don't think `mapreduce` would be able to figure this thing out by itself.

Comment: added more info. Thx for your help so far!

Comment: why down vote - what's wrong with this question?

Comment: I still don't understand. The code you're posting is not something you'd run in the `mongo` shell, and I don't see what's your input and what an example of your output should be. Could you clarify?

Comment: hmm maybe I need to write this clearer. The thing is I am not sure what I am looking for. mapreduce does not seem to let me do this and I am not sure if an aggregation pipeline is able to. Let me add some pseudo code

Comment: May be because when you posted the question you have not shown any attempt to solve it?

Comment: still working on it. I will post my solution once I have one

Comment: You'll need to remember that Map-reduce and the aggregation framework take a single document as input and do not do "cross-document" comparisons. Neither would create "new" documents in a way that I'd believe maps to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

To meet the requirement to respond in real-time as new data is added to the collection, you can make use of the MongoDB replication oplog. The oplog records each write to the database and is normally used to allow secondaries in a replica set to follow writes to the primary and apply the writes to the copy on the secondary. However it can also be used by other applications to monitor updates to the database as well.

To use this you would set up your mongod as a replica set, which will enable the oplog recording. This can be a single-node replica set if you have no need of the data replication function. See [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) for a description of how to convert a standalone mongod instance to a single-node replica set. In brief, you restart mongod specifying the --replSet option and then connect with a mongo shell and execute rs.initiate().

Having done this you now have an oplog, which shows up as the "oplog.rs" [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) in the "local" db. Once you have an oplog, you then create a [tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) to monitor write operations. A tailable cursor is conceptually similar to the Unix tail -f command: it receives a new result for each document that is added to the capped collection that it is monitoring.

In the mongo shell, it would look something like this; other language drivers have similar capabilities:

```
tailable = DBQuery.Option.tailable + DBQuery.Option.awaitData
db.oplog.rs.find({}).addOption(tailable).forEach(function (d) {
    print('--- op', d.op, 'ns', d.ns)
    printjson(d.o)
    // application logic goes here
})
```

Each time a write occurs, you will get a new document with several fields detailing the write. Of particular interest to you would be

- the op field, which indicates whether the write was an insert or an update; probably you are interested in inserts, for which the op field has the value 'i'
- the ns field, which indicates the namespace (database and collection) to which the write was done
- the o field, which is the new object value

So for example the preceding program prints the following for each new document inserted:

```
--- op i ns test.c
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5310a0a0ca57fb03897318f8"), "hello" : "world" }
```

You would then add the desired aggregation logic inside this loop, examining the inserted object to determine how to aggregate it with previous documents, possibly inserting aggregated documents into the db as a result.

You can specify query terms in the find() to ensure that you only see events of interest. For example, this version will give you only inserts on the "c" collection of the "test" database:

```
tailable = DBQuery.Option.tailable + DBQuery.Option.awaitData
db.oplog.rs.find({op:'i', ns:'test.c'}).addOption(tailable).forEach(function (d) {
    // application logic goes here
})
```

Does this help? Is there anything that needs further clarification?